# Increasing number of neurons in convolutional net?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~asamir/papers/icassp13_cnn.pdf) (chapter 2.4) describes a deep CNN as having two convolutional layers, consisting of 128 and 256 units respectively. From what I've learned, I understand that each convolutional layer should have fewer outputs than inputs, or at least not more. But in the paper 256-unit layer gets outputs from 128-unit layer as inputs. How is this possible? Could someone do a breakdown of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the follow-up paper (http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~gdahl/papers/cnnHFReLU_ASRU2013.pdf) it seems they're referring to the number of feature maps (see beginning of chapter 2). That is, they have 2 convolutional layers, the first one having 128 feature maps and the second 256.

Assuming this is correct, it'd be interesting to know if this usage of terminology (using "hidden units" to refer to feature map) is commonplace, as I'm not qualified to comment on that.

Comment: It seems you're right. [This paper,](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05899v1.pdf) that references both papers by T. Sainath, explicitly shows that 1st layer has 128 feature maps 11x3 neurons each, and 2nd layer has 256 feature maps 8x1 neurons each. Pretty confusing for a newcomer.